# Why are black areas being renderd both above and below the line graph?

Tags: dc.js

I have three charts rendering using dc.js and all of them render a black area below or above the line. I looked through the dc.css file for any fill options that were relevant, but I couldn't find any that had a positive effect.

[image: Here is an image of how it looks]

I', using Angular 7 as the framework to develop my application.
Json Data is in this form and has a few different device types:

```
{
device_ID: "DHT11-3fe381"
​​​​
device_type: "thermometer"
​​​​
time: "2019-02-26T00:56:54.000Z"
​​​​
value: 25.9
}
```

I use crossfilter to create a `timeDim` dimension and sort each value according to `device_type`:

```
    const timeDim = ndx.dimension((d) => d.time);

    var Thermo = timeDim.group().reduceSum((d) => {
      if (d.device_type === 'thermometer' && d.value <= 40) {
        return d.value;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
```

Then, I create my graphs:

```
const DTchart = dc.compositeChart('#graphT');

    DTchart
      .width(800)
      .height(300)
      .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 60})
      .dimension(timeDim)
      .group(device, 'value')
      .xUnits(d3.timeMinutes)
      .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([bottomDate, topDate]))
      .yAxisLabel('Thermometer reading')
      .xAxisLabel('Time')
      .brushOn(false)
      .elasticX(true)
      .elasticY(true)
      .controlsUseVisibility(true)
      .renderHorizontalGridLines(false)
      .compose([
        dc.lineChart(DTchart)
          .dimension(timeDim)
          .renderArea(false) // This didn't contribute anything
          .colors('RED')
          .group(Thermo) 
          .valueAccessor((d) => d.value)]
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for an SVG `path` element, which is used for line charts, is to display filled in black,

If you include `dc.css` it will [set `fill: none`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/075213030ebb778daa2f2ff13aab0ed7590fb9ac/style/dc.scss#L111). The axis font will fit better and the axis lines will be narrower too.

You didn't ask, but I think the vertical red lines are due to zeros in your data. If data is missing you could consider using [lineChart.defined](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.lineChart.html#defined__anchor) to put gaps in your lines instead of dropping to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the about lineChart.defined, it helped with making my graph look much better. and after making the appropriate change to the `dc.css` file, I no longer have issues with the graph appearance.